Raspberry Pi 4 ADS1115 No Hardware I2C on (scl,sda)=(3, 2)
I'm trying to do voltage measurements with RPi 4 Model B, ADS1115 and a voltage sensor. RPi is running the default Raspbian system. Python 3.11 is installed on the system. I've created virtual python environment with python -m venv ~/.env(because otherwise adafruit-circuitpython-ads1x15 doesn't get installed), activated it with source ~/.env/bin/activate and then installed adafruit-circuitpython-ads1x15 package with pip install adafruit-circuitpython-ads1x15. when I try to run this program(the real program is bigger but this is the smallest program to get the error):
from numpy import interp
import board
import time
import busio
import adafruit_ads1x15.ads1115 as ADS
from adafruit_ads1x15.analog_in import AnalogIn

# Initialize the I2C interface
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)

I get an error:
(.env) prototype@raspberrypi:~ $ python "/home/prototype/Downloads/RaspberryPiVoltageReporter/TestADS1115Main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/prototype/Downloads/RaspberryPiVoltageReporter/TestADS1115Main.py", line 9, in <module>
    i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/prototype/.env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/busio.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.init(scl, sda, frequency)
  File "/home/prototype/.env/lib/python3.11/site-packages/busio.py", line 168, in init
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: No Hardware I2C on (scl,sda)=(3, 2)
Valid I2C ports: ((1, 3, 2), (0, 1, 0), (10, 45, 44))
(.env) prototype@raspberrypi:~ $

The wiring for RPi and ADS1115 is as following:


The connection from RPi(left) to ADS1115(right) is as following:
(1)3.3V - VDD
(3)SDA - SDA
(5)SCL - SCL
(9)GND - GND
All the wires are tested on continuity and all the wires are fine. There's voltage between VDD and GND pins on ADS1115. The voltage is 2.4V. We're using a 1.5A USB-C charger as power supply, so that's why we have only 2.4V on the 3.3V pin, as I understand. The system also gives us low voltage warnings and sometimes RPi just restarts. Could this be the issue? Tomorrow we'll get a powerful enough power supply and we'll see if that's the issue but I feel like it's not. We also tested it using a battery with the same result. Everything seems to be correct as per guides online. Like this one, for example: https://how2electronics.com/how-to-use-ads1115-16-bit-adc-module-with-raspberry-pi/
Also, I noticed that in the error it says: No Hardware I2C on (scl,sda)=(3, 2), but the SCL and SDA pins are 5 and 3 respectively:

But I guess it's for GPIO 3 and GPIO 2. What is wrong here? Is it a broken ADS1115 or something? What can I try to troubleshoot this further? Thank you.

Someone voted to close the question but didn't even write a comment on why. OK.

Ok, figured it out. I had to enable I2C Interface on Raspberry Pi, which is disabled by default: Start > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Interfaces tab > I2C > Enabled, and then sudo raspi-config > Interfacing Options > I2C > Enter > Yes to Enable.
Here are a few that show how to do it:
https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2014/11/enabling-the-i2c-interface-on-the-raspberry-pi/
https://youtu.be/GSmq8ZH01Sg
A few tutorials I checked previously were missing this point.

really well done!

This first thing to do is connect the ADDR pin to GND (or another, see your datasheet for all options). If you forget to connect the ADDR pin of the ADS1115, left open will result in I/O bus error.
However your error is something else because it should detect the board via I2C.
After enabling the I2C Interface on Raspberry Pi via raspi-config, you can run the two commands below.
To debug I2C devices, try these two commands:
pi@dragon:~/venv $ i2cdetect -y 1
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 48 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --        

But having this is a very basic entry-level forgiving test. More things could still fail, but at least it detected your device (at 0x48 in this example).
A second test to do afterward is (replace 0x48 with your device detected address from the previous command)
# Success example:
pi@dragon:~ $ i2cdump -y 1 0x48
No size specified (using byte-data access)
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00: 53 c3 80 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    S???............
10: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................
f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    ................

This is successful because of the 53 c3 80 found above.
If it would fail the first lines would look like :
# Failing example:
pi@dragon:~ $ i2cdump -y 1 0x48
No size specified (using byte-data access)
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f    0123456789abcdef
00:  X  X  X 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00    XXX?............
(...)

